# tracking pointer location during Drag and drop

Tags: android, drag, gesture, ontouchlistener

I have a textview that supports drag and drop via a shadowbuilder.

```
     TheWord = new TextView(this);
     TheWord.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            shadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);              
            view.startDrag(null, shadow, view, 0);
            return false; //do not consume the event
        }
    });
```

I would like to be able to track the pointer/finger location while this drag and drop operation is in progress. My first approach was to add an onTouchEvent to the parent view (a LinearLayout), but that only works if the first touch took place outside of the textview. The second approach I tried was adding the textview to a GestureOverlayView but again gestures are only picked up if the starting touch was outside of the textview.

Any pointers would be appreciated.